# build tests: check if file exists in another project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, build, path, msbuild

I have a content file in my main project that sits at ~/bin/foo/FOO32.EXE that sometimes gets dropped out of source control (people are messing with .gitignore); this breaks our build every time.

I decided to make a basic test project that will make sure the file is where it needs to be.  The test project will run in our bamboo server as part of the build.

I want to test in my test project that the file exists, but the path could change dynamic based upon the build configuration (we build a 32-bit version and an Any CPU version, which means the bin directories can change a bit)

How can I verify that the file exists in my built project as part of a unit test?  I expect it to be something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void BbqExeExists()
{
    var basePath = ??? some expression that gets the main project's app directory
    var basefilePath = @"foo/FOO32.EXE";
    var fullPath = Path.Combine(basePath, basefilePath);

    Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(fullPath));
}
```

Comment: can't you just include file into project and have build action:none, copy to output: always? Testing for file presence in unit tests is generally pain and also depends on your test runner...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The problem is that our developers sometimes drop the file from the repository, so it gets deleted (first step of build process is sync with repo).  Setting the file to copy to output always doesn't help if it's not there.  I want to send the developer who deleted the file a nastygram for not paying attention, and identify that the build is invalid.

Comment: Maybe a pre-build event instead of a unit test? https://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/quick-tip-aborting-builds-in-visual-studio-based-on-file-contents/

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs but build should fail on missing file... Should be even more visible than failing test...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments mention: such tests do not really belong in the code of a unit test project I'd say. However it's fairly easy to achieve in msbuild itself. Put a target like this in the project which determines what your output directory is:

```
<Target Name="BbqExeExists" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <Error Condition="!Exists('$(TargetDir)/foo/FOO32.EXE')" Text="FRequired file missing"/>
</Target>
```

Because of the `BeforeTargets` attribute it will run before the rest of the build. Also I used `TargetDir` which is the one where the built executables usually go, though it's not really clear from your question if it's the one you need.